# Ionic Android hangs with least API level 28

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic3

When uploading my `apk` to the play store it hangs up with the below message. I already removed all SDKs and only have 28 installed in `Android Studio`, set `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="28"/>` in the `config.xml` but it keeps coming. How can I get fix this?

```
Your app currently targets API level 27 and must target at least API level 28 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 28. Learn how.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Google made it mandatory for all apps. In `config.xml` add

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
```

Your minimum SDK version can be lower than 28. I had 19 with target SDK 28. So, you can keep 27 as your minimum SDK if you need it.

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="27" />
```

If it still doesn't work, remove the android platform and add it again.